# Rails, use option_groups_from_collection_for_select for third level down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html-select

I have the following models .. Buildings *has_many* > Floors *has_many* > Rooms

I have gone over the the [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/option_groups_from_collection_for_select) for **option_groups_from_collection_for_select** and it only create form field select for 2 levels. Can it be set up for a third level down, selecting the Room, or is it impossible and I should look at other options? Thanks.

**EDIT:** (some more info)

**building.rb**

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :floors
end
```

**floor.rb**

```
class Floor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
  has_many: rooms

end
```

**room.rb**

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :floor
end
```

**Part of the form**

```
<div class="form-group">
              <% loc_options = option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@buildings, :floors, :name, :id, :name)%>
              <%= f.label :location, 'Location' %><br />
              <%= f.select :location, loc_options, {include_blank: 'Where is it located?'}, class:'form-control' %>
            </div>
```

I want to be able to select the room, but following the example in the api, I only able to set it up to the floor level so far.

Comment: could you post some code? Model associations and nested_attributes_for, with the view would help a bit

Comment: updated with some more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up abandoning this since HTML specs only allow for 2 levels, and instead opt for 3 select boxes using ajax to populate the each select field options below it.